# Why is this condition not working properly?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a number guessing game where you have three tries to guess a number between 1 and 5. After each wrong guess, it shows you how many tries you have left. When you guess it correct, you get a congratulations message. When you run out of guesses you get a message. However, I can't get the message for when you run out of guesses to run. Why does it not run?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tries=3;
    alert("Guess the number I'm thinking of between 1 and 5. You've got 3  tries.");
    var attempt =  prompt(tries+" tries remaining. Enter your guess.");
    var randomnumber = Math.random() * 5; 
    randomnumber = Math.ceil(randomnumber);
    while (tries>=2){
        if(attempt!=randomnumber){
            tries--;
            prompt("Wrong! You have " + tries + " left ");
        }
        else if(tries<1){
            alert("You have no tries left");
        }
        else {
            alert("Congratulations! You guessed the correct number");
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Think about your loop. What will be the value of `tries` when the loop ends? How does that differ to the value of `tries` you are looking for when you want to display the "no tries left" message.

Answer (score 4):

You only go into the loop when you have more than 2 or exactly 2 tries. Otherwise your if statements are not executed. You will probably have to seperate your if from your while.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tries=3;
    alert("Guess the number I'm thinking of between 1 and 5. You've got 3  tries.");
    var attempt =  prompt(tries+" tries remaining. Enter your guess.");
    var randomnumber = Math.random() * 5; 
    randomnumber = Math.ceil(randomnumber);
    while (tries-1 > 0){
        if(attempt!=randomnumber){
            tries--;
            prompt("Wrong! You have " + tries + " left ");
        }
        else {
            alert("Congratulations! You guessed the correct number");
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("You have no tries left");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your check `tries>=2`. I've modified your code a bit and it works as requested

```
var tries = 3;
alert("Guess the number I'm thinking of between 1 and 5. You've got 3  tries.");
var attempt = prompt(tries + " tries remaining. Enter your guess.");
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
while (tries-1 > 0) {
    if (attempt != randomnumber) {
        tries--;
        prompt("Wrong! You have " + tries + " left ");
    } else {
        alert("Congratulations! You guessed the correct number");
        return;
    }
}
alert("You have no tries left");
return;
```

- you can do get a random number on one line
- split the logic to two layers - while you have guesses check if you guessed right, otherwise return the "no guesses left" message

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKgc3/)

Comment: You only have 2 tries in this code. You should delete the "-1" from tries.

Comment: @Xatenev you have 3 tries.. Test the code. Editing in fiddle. Check out how while works http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp the `tries` variable gets decremented inside the loop

Comment: im sorry, your right, my fail - I did **not** test your code. I did **not** see, that the first prompt is already outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to affect each try to the `attempt` variable :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tries=3;
    alert("Guess the number I'm thinking of between 1 and 5. You've got 3  tries.");
    var randomnumber = Math.random() * 5; 
    randomnumber = Math.ceil(randomnumber);
    var attempt;
    var success = false;
    while (tries>0 && !success){
        attempt = prompt(tries+" tries remaining. Enter your guess.");
        tries--;
        if(attempt!=randomnumber){
            alert("Wrong! You have " + tries + " left ");
        } else {
            success = true;
        }
    }
    if(success){
        alert("Congratulations! You guessed the correct number");
    } else {
        alert("You have no tries left");
    }
</script>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdfuV/)